# Laravel 4 Dynamic Query Being Output Wrong

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a query function in a model of mine, and I am trying to have it take input for specific offsets and limit of returned rows.  This is the query function:

```
public static function friend_activity_json($start = 0, $number_of_posts = 2) {
        $friend_activity = DB::table('fanartists')
                        ->join('fans', 'fanartists.fan_id', '=', 'fans.id')
                        ->join('artists', 'fanartists.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                        ->orderBy('fanartists.created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->skip($start)
                        ->take($number_of_posts)
                        ->select('fans.fbid', 'fans.first_name', 'fans.last_name', 'fans.gender', 'fans.city', 'fanartists.artist_id', 'artists.stage_name', 'fanartists.created_at')
                        ->get();

        $posts = $json_encode($friend_activity);

        return $posts;

    }
```

When I have this query function called, I get the error:

```
    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
 syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
 to use near 'offset 0' at line 1 (SQL: select `fans`.`fbid`, `fans`.`first_name`, 
`fans`.`last_name`, `fans`.`gender`, `fans`.`city`, `fanartists`.`artist_id`, 
`artists`.`stage_name`, `fanartists`.`created_at` from `fanartists` inner join `fans` on 
`fanartists`.`fan_id` = `fans`.`id` inner join `artists` on `fanartists`.`artist_id` = 
`artists`.`id` order by `fanartists`.`created_at` DESC offset 0) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

Do you see what the issue is?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code, and it does work here, provided that I supply a not null, positive value for `$start` and `$number_of_posts`. When I don't do that for `$number_of_posts`, I get exactly the same query you are getting, so my guess is you're probably failing somewhere, when passing `$number_of_posts` to the function.

When checking the source code, on the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`'s `take` method, we can see why:

```
/**
 * Set the "limit" value of the query.
 *
 * @param  int  $value
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
 */
public function take($value)
{
    if ($value > 0) $this->limit = $value;

    return $this;
}
```

It only sets the limit value if the value is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` keyword and rowcount is missing in the query. That syntax is invalid.

The query should be something like:

```
... DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
```

The `OFFSET` keyword is part of the `LIMIT` clause, it can't appear just by itself. It's not at all clear why Eloquent is generating that, since it isn't valid SQL.

---

**Followup:**

Verify that `$number_of_posts` evaluates to a non-negative integer, so that a valid LIMIT clause can be generated. If `$number_of_posts` contains something other than a valid value for LIMIT, it's unlikely that it would generated invalid SQL.

(It looks like the error in the query builder is generating a statement that includes `OFFSET` without a corresponding `LIMIT`.

Comment: the documentation for Laravel is showing that I should use skip() and take() for offset and limit?  How should I amend my query in the above?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$users = User::offset(5)->get();
```

Use:

```
$users = User::limit(10000000)->offset(5)->get();
```

You must use limit() and offset() at the same time

1000000 - random big number, because we don't want to limit nothing